# Run jar into an apple script

Tags: java, macos, jar, arguments, applescript

I need to launch a .jar file (with theses arguments) from a packaged application with an apple script.

I try with an alert box but it's doesn't work...

```
on run {input, parameters}

set arg_s to ""

set sh to "DIR=$(dirname \"$0\") && cd \"$DIR\" || exit; pwd"
set pwd to do shell script "/bin/bash -c " & sh's quoted form & " " & (path to me)'s POSIX path's quoted form

repeat with argument in parameters
    copy arg_s & " " & argument to arg_s
end repeat

display notification arg_s with title arg_s subtitle arg_s sound name "Frog"

-- do shell script "java -jar " & pwd & "/Application.app/Contents/Java/App.jar" & result

return input
end run
```

Please see the error screenshot:

[image: error screenshot]

Thanks a lot..

Comment: How come you’re looping through `parameters` rather than `input` ?

Comment: Because I am a beginner in applescript. Thanks a lot. I modify my script accordingly with your message. But I still have an error when trying to run my application on the command line :

open -a Application.app --args A B C D E F

The error (on an alert box) :

Automator could not convert the input data to the desired type.

Comment: You could try changing `on run {input parameters}` to `on run argv`.  Then change `repeat with argument in parameters` to `repeat with argument in argv`.

Comment: I have the same error with this code :

`on run argv
 
 set arg_s to argv as list
 
 set sh to "DIR=$(dirname \"$0\") && cd \"$DIR\" || exit; pwd"
 set pwd to do shell script "/bin/bash -c " & sh's quoted form & " " & (path to me)'s POSIX path's quoted form
 
 display notification (item 1 of arg_s as Unicode text) with title (class of argv) subtitle (class of arg_s) sound name "Frog"
 
 -- do shell script "java -jar " & pwd & "/Application.app/Contents/Java/App.jar" & result
 
 return
end run`

Comment: It's really weird, to do a test I added before the script an "Ask for Text". Then I run the application on the command line: open -a Application.app --args "MyArgument". And the application starts well. But I wish I did not have the field at the beginning ... Look at this screenshot please.

[Step 1](https://i.imgur.com/XVcFj6j.png)
[Step 2](https://i.imgur.com/OdVUoIg.png)

Without "Ask for Text" step :

Comment: Without "Ask for Text" step, I have this error : [Error screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8NfC3Je.png)

"Automator could not convert the input data to the desired type."

Comment: I've no idea.  Out of interest, why are you using a **Run AppleScript** action when all of the active code is shell script wrapped inside s `do shell script` command ?  I think it would make more sense to use a **Run Shell Script** action.